# Install4j: Changing the destination directory in unattended mode

Tags: linux, install4j

I use install4j on Windows and Linux.
On Windows no problem with the unattendted mode.
But on Linux it doesn't taken into account the '-dir' option.
When I try this command it try to install in the default directory:

```
$ ./Test.sh -q -c -dir /home/chocard/Test -varfile response.varfile 
Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
You have no write permissions for the directory
/home/test
Please choose another directory.
You can set the destination directory by passing -dir [directory].
```

thanks for your help

Comment: the error says have no permission, try chmod u+w /home/test

Comment: I don't want to install in the default directory, but in the directory specify by '-dir' option.

Comment: Do you have an install directory in the reponse.varfile? From what I remember everything from it takes precedence over command line arguments.

Comment: Something sets the installation directory after the installer has been started. Run the installer with `-J-Dinstall4j.debug=true` to see when this happens. Side note: -q -c do not combine, just use -q. -c is for interactive console mode.

Comment: @SerbanConstantin that used to be the case in older versions (before 5.0), after that the -dir command option is never overridden and since 6.0 the "Load a response file" variable has an "Overwrite strategy" property that allows you to select in what cases existing variable definitions should be overridden.

Comment: @IngoKegel you are right I find the problem, thank a lot.